# Uploading Files to GridFS using Django mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I am using django-mongodb for my project.I need to upload images through admin interface and use gridfs file storage for storing images.Django-mongodb has "[Django storage backend for GridFS "](http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html#uploading-files-to-gridfs).I tried this and followed the steps but unable to store images.Objects are getting stored properly but not images with them.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from gridfsuploads import gridfs_storage

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(storage=gridfs_storage, upload_to='/')
```

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'tutorial'
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',

    'nonrelblog',
    'gridfsuploads'
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
```

Every-time I create a FileUpload object using admin interface the objects gets created successfully but I could not find uploaded image in the location I specified.I am not able to figure it out ,i even tested Djnago-non-rel guys [example project for using gridfs](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/tree/master/docs/source/code/tutorial/v4)
but same problem with that.Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the contents of the GridFS collection? It should default to database 'default', collection 'storage'. If you use the mongo shell like:

```
use default
db.storage.find()
```

Is there anything there? Or, are you overriding the default database or collection for gridfsuploads?